# How to compare JSON data from the same API request?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, request, xmlhttprequest

I'm still learning a lot about web development and javascript, so forgive me if my explanations are not clear.

I have a function to request from an API informations about cryptocurrency (Price, volume etc.) in a JSON file and then i display the price on the web page every 15 seconds.

I want to change the background color of the card where the price is displayed by comparing the actual price and the new one coming from the next request.

here's my javascript :

```
function requestPrice(url, domLocation){
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", url);
req.addEventListener("load", function() {
    if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400) { 
        var data = JSON.parse(req.responseText)
        domLocation.innerHTML = data.ticker.price + "$";
        erreur.innerHTML = "";
    } else {
        erreur.innerHTML = "Erreur: " + req.status + " " + req.statusText;
    }
});
req.addEventListener("error", function () {
    erreur.innerHTML = "Erreur";
});
req.send(null);
}

var btcPrice = document.getElementById('boxBTC'), erreur = 
document.getElementById('erreur');

setInterval(requestPrice("https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-eur", 
btcPrice), 15000);
```

I was thinking of a simple comparaison between the values and put this code in my loop but i need to stock the actual price somewhere to do the comparison with the new one coming and i'm stuck with that.

```
if (valueOf(data.ticker.price) <= valueOf(data.ticker.price)){
document.getElementById('overviewcard').style.backgroundColor = red;
} else {
document.getElementById('overviewcard').style.backgroundColor = blue;
}
```

Or

```
var overviewcard = getElementById('overviewcard');
if (data.ticker.price <= data.ticker.price){
overviewcard.style.backgroundColor = red;
} else { 
overviewcard.style.backgroundColor = blue;
}
```

here's the html :

```
    <div class="overviewcard">
       <span id="boxBTC">...</span>
       <span id="erreur"></span>
    </div>
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a myriad of ways, but the simplest is to grab the data from the actual HTML DOM element.

```
var currValue = document.getElementById('boxBTC').innerHTML;
if(valueOf(data.ticker.price) == currValue) {
    // do something
}
```

If you're `boxBTC` string is formatted too much (eg. if you make "1000" -> "1,000"), then you can always *also* store a data attribute of the raw value inside the DOM as a data attr.

```
// assigning the data
document.getElementById('boxBTC').setAttribute('data-val', price);
...
// accessing the data
document.getElementById('boxBTC').getAttribute('data-val');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, grab the data from the actual HTML DOM element was the key !

Comment: Is there any value inside that div? Does that div exist? If you need more help, you need to open a new question.

Comment: The div + span are empty at first, then with the first request the span take the value of my request (Price of a currency), my actual problem now is that i want to do the request every 30 second to update automatically the price in the span and display it. Can you help me from here, or do i have to create a all new post ?

Comment: I can tell you this should be a simple problem to solve, but if you're still struggling, open a new question!